# get img src on google images with puppeteer

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, puppeteer

Im doing a small script, and i want it to get a src from the first image on google photos, i have tried so many things, but i havent been able to get the src and save it into a variable. This is the script so far, i will be very grateful if you help me.

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
let imgSrc

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setViewport({
        width:1920,
        height:1080,
        isMobile: false
    })
    await page.goto('https://www.google.com/imghp');
    await         page.waitForXPath('/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/form/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/input')
    await page.click('#sbtc > div > div.a4bIc > input')
    await page.type('#sbtc > div > div.a4bIc > input', 'Tiras Glucomet Freestyle Optimun 50 unidades y 100 unidades')
    await page.click('#sbtc > button > div > span > svg')
    await page.waitForXPath('/html/body/div[2]/c-wiz/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/a[1]/div[1]/img')
    await page.click('#islrg > div.islrc > div:nth-child(1) > a.wXeWr.islib.nfEiy.mM5pbd > div.bRMDJf.islir > img')
    await page.waitForXPath('/html/body/div[2]/c-wiz/div[3]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/c-wiz/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/a/img')
    const data = await page.evaluate(() => {
        let src = document.querySelector('#Sva75c > div > div > div.pxAole > div.tvh9oe.BIB1wf > c-wiz > div.OUZ5W > div.zjoqD > div > div.v4dQwb > a > img').getAttribute('src')
        imgSrc = src
    })
    console.log(imgSrc)
})();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in function argument оf `page.evaluate()` is executed in browser context so it has not acces to variables of the puppeteer context including `imgSrc`. You need to transfer the data and then assign it to the variable:

```js
    imgSrc = await page.evaluate(() => {
        let src = document.querySelector('#Sva75c > div > div > div.pxAole > div.tvh9oe.BIB1wf > c-wiz > div.OUZ5W > div.zjoqD > div > div.v4dQwb > a > img').getAttribute('src')
        return src;
    })
    console.log(imgSrc)
```